# how to set password MariaDB on XAMPP 5.6.21

Tags: xampp, mariadb

I want set password mariaDB. I don't know What to do.
How to set password MariaDB on XAMPP 5.6.21 for windows?

Comment: The answer to your question is right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160663/xampp-set-root-user-password-for-mariadb/48218372#48218372)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just go to phpmyadmin, tab Users, click the user you want to edit in Edit Privileges link

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqladmin command to set password for root user. Please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160663/xampp-set-root-user-password-for-mariadb/48218372#48218372)