# XAMPP set root user password for MariaDB

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, mariadb

How do you set the root user password for MariaDB in XAMPP on Ubuntu/Kubuntu 16.04?

By default the root user does not have a password set.

I'm using XAMPP 7.1.11

Comment: If you still want to use WAMP for educational purposes, you can run an update on the `mysql.user` table, like `update mysql.user set Password = PASSWORD('thenewpassword') from mysql.user where User = 'root'`...

Comment: @Hackerman I'm using xampp on linux (WAMP is meant for windows). I want to know how that can be done on linux

Comment: It's the same procedure on xampp on Linux.

Comment: @Hackerman Found an alternative and posted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do it on both Windows and Linux.
On Windows, open command prompt, change directory to \xampp\mysql\bin and use mysqladmin to set password for root user i.e.

```
cd \xampp\mysql\bin
mysqladmin --user=root password "your_password"
```

On Linux (Ubuntu/Kubuntu), open terminal emulator and change directory to /opt/lampp/bin i.e.

```
cd /opt/lampp/bin
./mysqladmin --user=root password "your_password"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem fixed it like this:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";
quit;
```

Restart the database and you are good.

Key was this line:

```
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";
```

Answer (score 0):

This link to [Meer's World](https://www.meersworld.net/2019/02/how-to-set-root-password-in.html) made it easy for me because it's done through the phpMyAdmin screens directly and then the config.inc.php file. I tried the SQL query and command line methods described elsewhere and none worked properly. This was easy.