# Where can I locate database credentials in Xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, github, xampp

I'm working on a project and trying to host [this](https://github.com/techreagan/twitter-clone-php) with Xampp. It says I need to modify the app/config/config.php file according to my database credentials and also my root url. I don't know where to locate these credentials in Xampp. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

If your Xampp is installed locally, then http://localhost/phpmyadmin is where you can see/define accounts.

In your case, you need to set the root account ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218372/6309)).

Then you can reports those credentials (root+root-passwrd) to your config.php file.